# jquery reference this from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Google is not being helpful trying to find the answer to this question! :(

How do I properly reference `this.colour` from the parent object from within a jQuery function like this:

```
var obj = {
 colour: 'blue',
 do: function() {
  $.getJSON('getcolour.php', function(resp) {
    if (resp.colour == this.colour) { //<== this.colour doesnt = blue
     //match
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: Just use `obj.colour`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to obtain a reference to `this` *outside* of the call to `$.getJSON`:

```
do: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.getJSON('getcolour.php', function(resp) {
        if (resp.colour === self.colour) {  // use "self"
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

alternatively, on ES5 browsers, use `.bind` to set the context of the inner callback to `this`:

```
do: function() {
    $.getJSON('getcolour.php', function(resp) {
        if (resp.colour === this.colour) {
            // ...
        }
    }).bind(this);  // set the callback's context
}
```

jQuery's `$.proxy()` function can also be used on earlier browsers to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Excellent. Cheers! (Have to wait 7 minutes to accept the answer)

Answer (score 4):

You have two options here:

1) use a temporary variable to store the object's reference:

```
do: function() {
  var self = this;
  $.getJSON('getcolour.php', function(resp) {
    if (resp.colour == self.colour) { ... }
  });
};
```

If you choose this way, you have both "local `this`" (as getJSON handler context object) and "object `this`" easily available in your handler. But you have, of course, to define that temporary variable. `self` is one of the most common names usually chosen for this purpose, but it actually can be any identifier available - as long as it doesn't overlap with other variables' names).

2) use the function made right for this: [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
do: function() {
  $.getJSON('getcolour.php', $.proxy(function(resp) {
    if (resp.colour == this.colour) { ... }
  }, this));
};
```

With this approach you have replaced the context object of the handler - it now points to `this` (as an object which defines `do` function).

Answer (score 3):

The `this` that you are trying to refer to is being shadowed by a `this` that refers to the context within the `getJSON` callback. Use a different variable name.

```
do: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.getJSON('getcolour.php', function(resp) {
        if (resp.colour == self.colour) { //<== this.colour doesnt = blue
         //match
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below, i think in your code **this** refers ajax scope

```
var obj = {
 colour: 'blue',
 do: function() {
  var myObj=this;
  $.getJSON('getcolour.php', function(resp) {
   if (resp.colour == myObj.colour) { //<== this.colour doesnt = blue
 //match
}
 });
}
}
```