# Get parent function name inside jquery ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
arguments.callee.caller.name
```

I get that is how you get the parent.

```
function parent() {
    ajax{
        success: function(result) {
            doOnSuccessFunction() {
            }
        }
    }
}

function doOnSuccessFunction() {
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller.name);
}
```

I am wanting the doOnSuccessFunction to log "parent" in the output, but it logs blank because the success: function() is actually the parent. Is there a way to get the parent of the ajax call I guess is really the question. Not sure how this would work with scope coming into play and nested functions. Hoping someone has encountered this already and might have a solution.

### Edit:

This is what i have come up with so far, to keep it as dynamic as possible. Feel free anyone to let me know if there is anything else?

```
function parent() {
    ajax{
        callback: arguments.callee.name,
        success: function(result) {
            doOnSuccessFunction(callback) {
            }
        }
    }
}

function doOnSuccessFunction(callback) {
    console.log(callback);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474468/jquery-reference-this-from-parent

Answer (score 1):

The function you give in the `success` parameter is an anonymous function. It is not executed when you call the `parent` function. It is executed later (and maybe asynchronously). So you can't really get `parent` using `arguments`. (If you try, you'll probably get a internal function of your library)

You can use a parameter and give the function when you do the call :

```
function parent() {
    ajax{
        success: function(result) {
            doOnSuccessFunction(parent);
        }
    }
}    

function doOnSuccessFunction(parent) {
    console.log(parent.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i am not really looking to specify the name of the parent. I am trying to keep thing dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a parameter like this:

```
ajax{
        success: function(result) {
            doOnSuccessFunction("parent") {
            }
        }


function doOnSuccessFunction(parent) {
            }
```

Comment: Thanks but i am not really looking to specify the name of the parent. I am trying to keep thing dynamic.